# Ansible limit not working on groups

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have following two inventories under `inventories/dc`

**dc1**

```
[kafka]
k1.test
```

**dc2**

```
[kafka]
k2.test
```

and jinja template file

**test.j2**

```
{% for item in groups['kafka'] %} {{item}} {% endfor %}
```

Since my playbook while running on one cluster needs information of other cluster, I am running the playbook this way:

`ansible-playbook -i inventories/dc testplaybook.yml -u root --limit dc1`

But, problem with this approach is that `groups['kafka']` lists kafka from both cluster. How can restrict playbook to list kafka from same cluster only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `play_hosts` variable to check if the host from `groups['kafka']` is in the target hosts.

```
{% for item in groups['kafka'] %}{% if item in play_hosts %} {{item}} {% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

I'd consider refactoring your inventory so that there aren't 2 definitions of the same group. Something like `dc1_kafka` and `dc2_kafka` maybe?